# Replacing SAM-constructor with lambda with covariant type

Tags: kotlin

I have got the following Java interfaces:

```
interface Action1<T> {

    void call(T t);
}

interface Test<T> {

    void test(Action1<? super T> action)
}
```

And the following Kotlin class:

```
interface A {
    fun go()
}

abstract class Main {

    abstract fun a(): Test<out A>

    fun main() {
        a().test(Action1 { it.go() })
        a().test { it.go() }
    }
}
```

Now in the function `main`, the first statement compiles, but IntelliJ gives a warning that the SAM-constructor can be replaced with a lambda.
This would result in the second statement.

However, this second statement does not compile, because `it` has type `Any?`, not `A`. Removing the `out` modifier makes it compile again.

Why does this happen?

---

The use case of this is when the implementing class of `Main` needs to return `Test<B>` for the function `a()`, where `B` implements `A`:

```
class B : A {

    override fun go() {
        TODO()
    }
}

class MainImp : Main() {
    override fun a(): Test<out A> {
        val value: Test<B> = object : Test<B> {
            override fun test(action: Action1<in B>?) {
                TODO()
            }
        };

        return value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a compiler bug. You can track it here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12238.